# Generating new id each time button is clicked

Tags: php, sql

I am working on a reservation system where I need to generate a unique id for each reservation and display it on the form inside the modal when the user clicks on "Add new reservation"

I used ajax and SQL to do that however sometimes I get duplicates of ids. What I do is each time the button is clicked I insert the id into a table and

That's is my code

```
 <script>
function showId() {

  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else { // code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (this.readyState==4 && this.status==200) {
      document.getElementById("show-id").defaultValue=this.responseText;
    }
  }
  xmlhttp.open("GET","getid.php?=",true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>


<script>

$(function () {
    $('#openModal').on('click', function () {

  showId();



var mx_val=$("#show-idi").val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "insert-id.php",
            data: {mx_val:mx_val},
            dataType: "JSON",
            success: function(data) {
           /*  $("#message").html(data); */
             getDu();
          /*  $("p").addClass("alert alert-success");*/
            },
            error: function(err) {
  $("#message").html("Saved!");
            $("p").addClass("alert alert-success");

              console.log(err);
            }
        });






    });
});




</script>
```

insert-id.php

```
<?php


include('db.php');

$mx_val=$_POST['mx_val'];


require_once("dbcontroller.php");
$db_handle = new DBController();
$query ='SELECT max(mx_val) from mxvalue';
$results = $db_handle->runQuery($query);
foreach($results as $references) {
$maxvalue =  $references["max(mx_val)"] +1;

} 
$stmt = $DBcon->prepare("INSERT INTO mxvalue (mx_val) VALUES ('$maxvalue')");


if($stmt->execute())
{
  $res="Data Inserted Successfully:";
  echo json_encode($res);
}
else {
  $error="Not Inserted,Some Problem occured.";
  echo json_encode($error);
}
```

getid.php

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect('','','','');
if (!$con) { die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
} mysqli_select_db($con,"ajax_demo");
$sql="SELECT max(mx_val) from mxvalue";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
$maxid = $row["max(mx_val)"] +1;
?><?php echo $maxid; ?><?php } mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: "where I need to generate a unique id for each reservation"...use an auto-increment field in your database table like everyone else. You don't need to (and should not) handle this yourself, you'll always have concurrency issues. The database can, and will, and is designed to, handle this for you automatically, and you barely have to write any code at all.

Comment: ADyson, as mentioned I need to know the id of the reservation before the reservation is created. I have other reasons too!

Comment: you can create a mostly-empty row to get the ID, and then fill the rest of it in later. That's a very common pattern. Although, consider if you really _need_ the ID up front before any details have been submitted? Why is that, precisely? What functional advantage does it provide? What would go wrong if you didn't do that, and just waited for the user to complete the necessary details before creating a record and an ID?

Comment: yes you can. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php will get you the last ID inserted _using the current connection_ (which of course will be separate for each user, since they are in different sessions). Again, that's the normal way to do it. You don't ever rely on just selecting the most recent row from the database. The way you're doing it _now_ is the way to ensure you get the IDs mixed up and/or duplicated.

Comment: I need to know the id because at a later stage of the form this id will be used to populate another table. I cannot use the last inserted id method as two people could be creating reservation a second apart. The form is a multi step process where I need to save the data first in order to save other information in another table.

Comment: " I cannot use the last inserted id method as two people could be creating reservation a second apart"...re-read my last comment to understand why this is _not_ an issue. The last inserted ID will be the last inserted ID **for the current user** . It will not get it confused with another user, ever.

Comment: Ohhh  I didn't know!! Thanks it makes everything so much easier :)

Comment: "at a later stage of the form this id will be used to populate another table"...but still, you don't have to save data to that second table until everything is complete, either, or at least until you have got at least some data from the user. You don't really need to make the ID before the user has input _anything_. Make it at the last possible moment before it's needed. Also take into account my comments on the answer below regarding security, if you haven't already.

Comment: "it makes everything so much easier"...yes. Last inserted ID would be pretty much useless as a concept if it didn't work like this. As it stands, it's very useful and is the standard method for getting the row ID last created by the current session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use ids based on unix timestamp mixed with some random number, or use a uuid generator Like:

https://github.com/ramsey/uuid

By this two ways you will not get duplicate ids ever

Comment: why complicate things? The simplest, easiest and most reliable thing is to let SQL generate an integer ID from an auto-increment field.

Comment: ADyson. Using Auto Increment in a reservation system may help other people to predict all ids and of course see all reservations. specially if there is no other layers of security when someone is trying to check his/her reservation status.

Comment: "of course see all reservations"...that's a security issue, not specifically an issue with how the IDs are generated. The reservation would have to be associated to the correct users/roles at the time of creation, which shouldn't be very difficult. IMO that's not in itself a reason to use a different, more complicated solution.